# Create Maven child project

Tags: eclipse, maven, inheritance, pom.xml

I know I can create a maven project with `mvn archetype:generate` which will generate a pom.xml file for me.

How do I create a maven project that is going to be a child project?  I want the child pom.xml that is created to have the necessary elements that will link it the parent project.

I could of course manually enter in the necessary elements into the child pom.xml, but I was wondering if there is a way to do it with Maven.

Comment: try to look at Apache-Camel https://github.com/apache/camel look at pom.xml It should give you brief idea abt how to do it

Comment: If your ide had a convenient way to do this, would you accept it as an answer?  If so, what IDE are you using?

Comment: @tieTYT I use maven in windows cmd prompt.  I use Eclipse for Java development.  Sure, I would accept an answer if I could do what I'm trying to do in Eclipse.

Comment: I use IDEA so I won't be any help.  But you may want to include that tag on your question.

Comment: @tieTYT suggestion taken.  Eclipse tag added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do it with eclipse: Simply create a mavenmodule (your child project) and name the parentproject in the `Parent Project` section.

*Note:* your parent project should be in the eclipseworkspace too.

for further information have a look at: http://skillshared.blogspot.de/2012/11/how-to-create-multi-module-project-with.html